# What "kitchen" is Joe referring to?

Tags: plot-explanation, mank

In *Mank* (2020), Joe calls Mank, who is being massaged by a lady.

> Joe: I hear you're hunting dangerous game. Word on the street is
> radio's  golden boy wants to go toe-to-toe with Willie Hearst, and
> you're helping  in **the kitchen**.

“Radio boy” refers to Welles, who — before *Citizen Kane* — made a name for
himself as a radio and theater actor-director in his 20s.

What "kitchen" is Joe referring to?

Comment: Downvoter ought to post a comment explaining their downvote. It's not at all clear what is objectionable about this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Joe is [mixing metaphors](https://www.studiobinder.com/blog/what-is-a-mixed-metaphor-definition/) here, with phrases like:

- Hunting dangerous game
- Going toe-to-toe
- Helping in the kitchen

He's explaining that Welles and Mank are going to make a movie clearly based on William Randolph Hearst (Citizen Kane) and that this is dangerous because Hearst is a powerful man.  The phrase "helping in the kitchen" appears to just imply that Mank is helping with the project, almost "cooking up the project" with Welles.

Comment: I like my mixed metaphors like I like my women: strong, scatterbrained, and -- look, a communist!

Comment: That has to be a quote from somewhere right?

Comment: From right here!